# How to place aspx-files in seperate Web Application Projects in one solution?

Tags: asp.net

We have been building ASP.Net websites for many years. During this time we gathered a lot of knowledge of ASP.Net. We know what to use, a what not. One problem is still, persistently, bugging us. I hope to solve this for once and for all.

We have a fairly large solution with lots of aspx-files. All aspx-files reside in one Web Application Project. This single big WAP needs to be split in multiple smaller projects. The exact reasoning is beside the point, please believe me ;-).

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, but I am still unsure what the best way would be. We use ASP.Net 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

**This is our current work-around (which we do not like)**

1. Create a WAP (Runner).
2. Create a second WAP (ProjectA)
3. Create a third WAP (ProjectB)
4. Delete the web.config's in ProjectA and ProjectB
5. Create a simple aspx-file in Runner, ProjectA and ProjectB with a hello world message
6. Remove ProjectA and ProjectB
7. Go to Windows Explorer
8. Move the folders ProjectA and ProjectB inside the folder Runner
9. Go back to Visual Studio
10. Add Existing Project to solution (ProjectA and ProjectB)
11. Hit F5
12. Navigate to http://localhost:4867/WebForm1.aspx
13. Navigate to http://localhost:4867/ProjectA/WebForm1.aspx
14. Navigate to http://localhost:4867/ProjectB/WebForm1.aspx

Tada! The above works, but it feels like a hack and it smells awful. Is there a better way?

Comment: With help from @Ray and @Dirk it is clear that there is no proper solution, only ugly hacks. Too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/08/16/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Creating-Sub_2D00_Web-Projects-using-the-VS-2005-Web-Application-Project-Option.aspx) is what Scott Guthrie says on this. I think the second method is a superset of your procedure. In my opinion you are right: This is a hack - but the official one.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a new solution, and creating your required new empty web application projects under it. Then, manually copy your files from their original locations into the proper new folders which were created when you created the empty projects. After all the files are in place, go back to VS. Set Solution Explorer to 'Show All Files'. Select the the files you need in each project, right click, and select 'Include in Project'.

The only wrinkle I can think of is that creating all web applications will mean you have a web.config file in each. If this is what you need, then fine. Otherwise, you create some of the projects as class libraries.

Comment: thank you, but this is unfortunately not what I am looking for. a) you cannot add a aspx-file to a library, b) when having two WAPs and F5-ing the first one, you cannot access aspx-files in the second one (just to put it simply). Any suggestions?

Comment: I have a number of class library projects which include ascx files (though not aspx). I just tried an aspx as an experiment and it was included with no trouble. What is the error you are getting? I am not sure I understand your (b) - is there an error message? Do you have web.config files in multiple folders? Also, I never use F5. I run the site normally in IIs, and for debugging, I use 'Attach To Process' on the debug menu

Comment: Hi Ray. Thanks for helping. It is appreciated. a) When adding an item to my new Class Library there simply is no option to add an Web Form. b) we debug via IIS too :) The only way to make this work is by setting up a virtual directory in iis. It works, but doesn't feel right. At the same time I do understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Your are correct, you can't add a web form as a new item. What you do is select the existing file(s) in solution explorer, right click, and select 'include in project'. I use a single virtual directory pointing to my root in IIS (because I use IIS 5 on XP, and that is how it works). But I don't need more virtual directories for other folders. What error do you get?